# Upgrading from Jboss Community edition to Enterprise Edition

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

We're currently in the process of purchasing enterprise edition of Jboss and facing some delay in the purchase cycle.
As an interim measure, thinking of starting the project with community edition and later on applying license to this, to convert to enterprise edition.

Is this doable ? Has anyone done this before ?

Appreciate any pointers on this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a developer subscription from Red Hat for no cost.  This will allow you to download any of the Red Hat software and access the Red Hat knowledge base.